# How to add exsisting in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have just download source code on github, and it has so many files. I want to import them to VC++ for build it. But it has below bug.

[image]

How can i edit it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your project, then from Solution Explorer, select properties like in the below image.
   [image]
2. From the pop up window select C/C++ from the right pane, then General like in the image below.
   [image]
3. Select edit.
4. Finally, select the folder where your header files, you want to include, are.
   [image]